# The difference between XPOST and XPUT

Tags: rest, post, curl, elasticsearch, put

I am learning `Elasticsearch`, I found that `XPOST` and `XPUT` are in general the same when 'update' or 'replace' documents. They all change the field values.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty' -d '
{
  "name": "Jane Doe"
}'

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1/_update?pretty' -d '
{
  "doc": { "name": "Jane Doe" }
}'
```

So they all changed the name field to "Jane Doe". I am wondering whats the difference between `XPOST` and `XPUT` in the above context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two commands are not at all the same. The first one (with `PUT`) will **update a full document**, not only the field you're sending.

The second one (with `POST`)  will do a **partial update** and only update the fields you're sending, and not touch the other ones already present in the document.

Comment: Please mention that this is because he is using the _update API. ElasticSearch documents are immutable, they cannot be changed, only replaced. The update API must obey the same rules. Externally, it appears as though we are partially updating a document in place. Internally, however, the update API simply manages the same retrieve-change-reindex process. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html

Comment: From the user's perspective, "changed" or "replaced" makes no difference. Usually, one wants to "update" his document with some new values, and the way ES deals with this internally is not of big interest to the user. Both full updates and partial updates will actually replace the underlying document and increment the version, so that's not really important here to distinguish between the difference of PUT and POST. However, it's true that the POST verb is used only with the `_update` endpoint, and your point is valid.

Answer (score 4):

firstly, -X is a flag of curl. 
please see -X in the man page. It is same as --request. You can specify which HTTP method to use (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE etc)
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Regarding POST and PUT, they are HTTP methods or "verbs".

ElasticSearch provides us with a REST API. According to REST practices, POST is for create and PUT is for updating a record.

Please see: 
http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: The `Elasticsearch` tutorial uses `XPOST` for updating documents, as in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_updating_documents.html

Comment: @daiyue please see -X in the man page. It is same as --request. You can specify which HTTP method to use  ie POST, GET, PUT, DELETE etc 
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 3):

HTTP PUT:

PUT puts a file or resource at a specific URI, and exactly at that URI. If there's already a file or resource at that URI, PUT replaces that file or resource. If there is no file or resource there, PUT creates one. PUT is idempotent, but paradoxically PUT responses are not cacheable.

HTTP 1.1 RFC location for PUT

HTTP POST:

POST sends data to a specific URI and expects the resource at that URI to handle the request. The web server at this point can determine what to do with the data in the context of the specified resource. The POST method is not idempotent, however POST responses are cacheable so long as the server sets the appropriate Cache-Control and Expires headers.

The official HTTP RFC specifies POST to be:

Annotation of existing resources;
Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list, or similar group of articles;
Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form, to a data-handling process;
Extending a database through an append operation.
HTTP 1.1 RFC location for POST

Difference between POST and PUT:

The RFC itself explains the core difference:

The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed entity. That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway to some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts annotations. In contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource. If the server desires that the request be applied to a different URI, it MUST send a 301 (Moved Permanently) response; the user agent MAY then make its own decision regarding whether or not to redirect the request.
Using the right method, unrelated aside:

One benefit of REST ROA vs SOAP is that when using HTTP REST ROA, it encourages the proper usage of the HTTP verbs/methods. So for example you would only use PUT when you want to create a resource at that exact location. And you would never use GET to create or modify a resource.

upvote if it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

PUT method is idempotent so if you hit payload with put method, it will create first time only and if you hit the same request again and again, it won't create new records, it will simply update the previously created.
On the other hand if you hit the payload with POST method no of times you will create a no of entries of same payload.